# Accessing column data from a CSV file in Django 2.0

Tags: python, django

From Django Admin I am setting the import button in order to import .csv files. 
Everything works fine as long as I set the models.py with CharField.

As I turn it into FloatField:

```
from django.db import models

class Moon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    code_name = models.IntegerField() 
    planet = models.FloatField()
    lumen = models.FloatField()
    power = models.FloatField()
```

It happen that with decimal pointed with comma "," I receive the error for the row[3] when the data has float number separeted with comma and not with a point:

> could not convert string to float: '0,00'

I've red dozens of info about that topic but none of these did help me to figure out my issue. As far I've understood, my priority here is to pre-process the .csv file with thousands of rows, giving it a pre-format before to upload into the admin.py. 
Am I correct? Any hint on how to proceed?

```
def import_csv(self, request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        csv_file = TextIOWrapper(request.FILES["csv_file"].file, encoding='utf-8')
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

        # create Moon object from passed in data
        for row in reader:
            Moon.objects.get_or_create(
                name=row[0],                         <-- that row is a str
                code_name=row[1],                    <-- that row is an int
                planet=row[2],                       <-- that row is an int
                lumen=row[3],                        <-- that row is a float
                power=row[4]                         <-- that row is a float
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `str.replace(",", '.')`

**Ex:**

```
def import_csv(self, request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        csv_file = TextIOWrapper(request.FILES["csv_file"].file, encoding='utf-8')
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

        # create Moon object from passed in data
        for row in reader:
            Moon.objects.get_or_create(
                name=row[0],                         <-- that row is a str
                code_name=row[1],                    <-- that row is an int
                planet=row[2],                       <-- that row is an int
                lumen=row[3].replace(",", '.'),                        <-- that row is a float
                power=row[4].replace(",", '.')                         <-- that row is a float
```

Comment: it works thank you very much!    And what if the value imported is null, empty row?